# How to unfocus a file using keyboard on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gui

This is my folder:

[image: Just opened folder]

This is how it looks like when I press the menu key on my keyboard just after opening the folder:

[image: Menu key pressed after opening the folder]

As you can see above, it is the same menu that we get when we right click the mouse on any empty (white) place in the folder.

This is how it looks like when I press my cursor keys after opening the folder:

[image: Cursor key pressed after opening the folder]

This is how it looks like when I press the menu key on my keyboard in this state:

[image: Menu key pressed after focusing a file]

Now my question is, is there any way to go to the state at the 1st picture from the state at the 3rd picture by *only* using the keyboard? Alternatively, going from picture 3 to this is also acceptable:

[image]

Comment: esc then ctrl+space if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> should deselect the file. Note that you can select a file only with <kbd>space</kbd> but not deselect it, you need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as well for that.

Comment: By the way, I guess it is not possible to open the folder menu, while keeping the selected files in the folder, right? Because when you select some files and right click on an empty space, focus is lost there too.

Comment: I will ask it as a new question.